# How to Force Regex to Capture Largest Match?

Tags: regex, web, regex-greedy

I am trying to prevent malicious injections to a website. The way I am doing this is creating a function that "trims" any extra parts off of a URL that would make it illegal.

In order for a URL to be legal, it must stick to the following format:

> (anything)(one of several specificied path predecessors)(specific page)

So for example, say your path predecessors are...

> ["services", "services/city", "specials", "specials/limited/"]

Some sample inputs and results:

> www.fake.com/services/home -> (legal, no trim) ->
>   www.fake.com/services/home
>
> www.fake.com/services/city/nyc -> (legal, no trim) -> 
>   www.fake.com/services/city/nyc
>
> www.fake.com/services/city/nyc/fakeinjection.txt -> (illegal) ->
>   www.fake.com/services/city/nyc
>
> www.fake.com/specials/limited/california/fake/fake/fake.bak ->
>   (illegal) -> www.fake.com/specials/limited/california

So I wrote the following regular expression to match only the legal part of the input URL:

```
/.*(services|services\/city|specials|specials\/limited)\/[^\/]*/gi
```

The problem with this is that it is not always capturing the largest possible match, and so it is inadvertently trimming off too much. For example:

www.fake.com/services/city/nyc -> (should be legal, should not trim) -> 
www.fake.com/services/city/

I understand why this is happening, I think. I believe it is capturing the first thing it sees and matching that. But I need to force it to take the biggest one possible, only trimming if necessary. I thought the "greedy" flag would help do this, but this is not the case.

Could anyone please provide some guidance on a solution? It would be much appreciated.

(PS. In case it makes a difference, the language I am using is javascript)

Comment: [`.*(services\/city|specials\/limited|services|specials)\/[^\/\n]*`](https://regex101.com/r/wW0kQ3/1) - longer alternatives should come first.

Comment: For the sake of this specific problem, www.fake.com/services/fakeinjection.txt would be legal, because it would match (anything)(one of several specificied path predecessors)(specific page).

Comment: +1 for @WiktorStribiżew, in the round brackets you have to put first what you want the engine to analyze first.

Comment: Order matters. But you could also make the longer parts optional. As in `/^.*(?:services(?:\/city)?|specials(?:\/limited)?)\/[^\/]*$/`

Comment: Is the alternation list "dynamic" or do you define it manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an unanchored alternation group, you should put the longest alternatives first. In any NFA regex, the first branch that matches stops processing the alternation group and goes on with the subsequent patterns.

So, you can use

```
/.*(services\/city|specials\/limited|services|specials)\/[^\/]*/
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wW0kQ3/1)

You may further enhance this list in case you manually create the pattern using optional groups to lessen backtracking:

```
/.*(services(?:\/city)?|specials(?:\/limited))\/[^\/]*/
```

or even

```
/.*(s(?:ervices(?:\/city)?|pecials(?:\/limited)))\/[^\/]*/
```